# How to create a function that ignores any arguments and always throws an exception?

Tags: clojure

`(constantly (throw (Exception. "Don't call me")))` is how I expected to do this, based on the Clojure [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/constantly) for `constantly`:

> `(constantly x)`
>
> Returns a function that takes any number of arguments and returns x.

But when I try to use constantly to create a mock function that always throws, the exception gets thrown immediately, where I am trying to define the function. Is `constantly` supposed to evaluate it's body right away, and cache the result? Am I running into the equivalent of C's dreaded Undefined Behaviour (in this case,  "all bets are off once you depend on side effects")?

```
user=> (constantly (throw (Exception. "but not right now")))

Exception but not right now  user/eval8734 (form-init1747541642059004341.clj:1)
user=> (repeatedly (throw (Exception. "but not right now")))

Exception but not right now  user/eval8736 (form-init1747541642059004341.clj:1)
```

What is the idiomatic way to create to mock a callback function in a test, so that it will throw an error if called?

Comment: Oh snap, I see the problem, `(throw (Exception. "but not right now"))` is an expression that throws an exception, not a constant or an expression that evaluates to one. `constantly` just isn't going to work here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constantly` is a function; it evaluates its argument and then returns a function that will return that evaluated result. If you want to write a function that ignores all its arguments and evaluates some expression every time it is called, you can do something like this:

```
(fn [& _] (throw (Exception. "Don't call me")))
```

Example:

```
((fn [& _] (throw (Exception. "Don't call me"))) :foo :bar)
;=> java.lang.Exception: Don't call me
```

You could also write a macro to create functions that ignore their arguments:

```
(defmacro ignore-args [& exprs]
  `(fn ~'[& _] ~@exprs))
```

Example:

```
((ignore-args (throw (Exception. "Don't call me"))) :foo :bar)
;=> java.lang.Exception: Don't call me
```

I'm not entirely sure how useful such a macro would be, though, because with any sort of descriptive name (`ignore-args`, in this case), it would take longer to type than `(fn [& _] ,,,)` and doesn't really convey more semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a function that always throws an exception, you can do this:

```
(defn blowup [& args] (throw (Exception. "I just blew up")))
```

If you're looking for a way to make those on demand, try this instead:

```
(defn explosives-factory [e] (fn [& args] (throw e)))
```

You can see it in practice here:

```
user=> (defn explosives-factory [e] (fn [&args] (throw e)))
#'user/explosives-factory
user=> (def blowup (explosives-factory (Exception. "Boom!")))
#'user/blowup
user=> (blowup 123)

Exception Boom! sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
```